# Django - paginator table i need to show the most recent activity first

Tags: python, django, paginator, django-pagination

i have a table showing data from the database but i need it to show the most recent first

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgz0A.png)
if u see the picture there is in "monto" a 0.03 thats shown like the last one but it is the most recent in the database, i need the table to show the most recent activity first

#### Views.py

```
def index(request):
    monto = Transacciones.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    paginator = Paginator(monto , 7)

    page_number = request.GET.get('pagina')
    page_obj= Paginator.get_page(paginator,page_number)

    context = {
        'page_obj': page_obj , 
        
    }

    return render(request, 'Admin/Index.cshtml',context)
```

#### table html

```
<div class="">
            <div class="">
                <table class="table h1color bgcolorwhite">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>FECHA</th>
                            <th>MONTO</th>
                            <th>TIPO</th>
                            <th>MONTO COMPRADO BTC</th>
                            <th>MONTO RETIRADO CLP</th>
                            <th>ESTADO</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for a in page_obj %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="">{{a.date}}</td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold;">{{a.amount}}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">{{a.tipo_transaccion}}</td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold;">{{a.monto_comprado_btc}}</td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold;">{{a.monto_retirado_clp}}</td>
                            <td style="">{{a.status}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

srry if my english was bad... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try with `monto = Transacciones.objects.filter(owner = request.user).order_by('-fetcha')`

Comment: You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the order_by method. Like Transacciones.objects.filter(owner = request.user).order_by('-fetcha').The result will be ordered by fetcha in descending manner.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked perfectly, had to change DateField to DateTimeField on models for it to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

If views.py file fetch the data like the following to get the activities in order "recent to last":

```
monto = Transacciones.objects.filter(owner = request.user)[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks!, i ended up using .orderby :D